# How to create two side multi select with attached layout

Tags: jquery, layout, multiselect.js

I need to implement two side multi select structure with customization like when i select value from left section it will shift right section without pop up value from left section.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you using plain HTML/CSS/Js or angular?

Comment: I tried using jquery but above scenario value pop up (remove) form left section those i  need to avoid. Also if you have solution using angular 2 or more then its helpful to me.

Comment: please post your code here so we could help.

Comment: I am not able to start yet. I am thinking to use below ref but there is an issue with pop up value.

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Two-side-Multi-Select-Plugin-with-jQuery-multiselect-js/